# Alternative to "For the purpose of comparison"

Tags: synonyms

In my current paper I have the sentence

> For the purpose of comparison we also provide Definition 1, which is more concise and complete than previous similar definitions.

The sentence needs to be shortened (I am fighting with every syllable). So I am wondering whether I could shorten this to one of the suggestions of https://www.powerthesaurus.org/for_the_purpose_of_comparison/synonyms. In particular I am considering

- for comparison purposes
- for comparative purposes

Could a native speaker say whether these are sounding smooth or somewhat awkward?

Comment: You don't need to explicitly mention ***purpose*** - just say ***for comparison***. And is it really necessary to explicitly point out that *your* definition is "more concise and complete than previous similar definitions"? Which is an odd pairing anyway. Usually things can be either "more complete" ***or*** "more concise" - are you sure you're being honest there?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Regarding "are you sure you're being honest there": Well, I think so. It's math. The more rigorous you define, the more complete you get, and also the more concise (as in "short") you get. My definition is pretty short, but also covers everything exactly as intended. It is a general interesting phenomenon that the more systematic you write, the more exact you get, but also the shorter your text becomes.

Comment: I don't really understand that. But maybe there's a difference between how "mathematical definitions" work, and how ***natural language*** works.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes, there really is, imho. I would say, not just mathematical definitions, but I would also say mathematical language in general. It is sort of like natural language, but not quite how people would usually speak. It is a bit like "lawer language", but worse :-D - or a bit like computer programming languages. Of course, not my entire paper is written in this style, but at least the definitions and proofs are.

Comment: I'd shorten it this way: _For comparison we provide Definition 1, which is more concise and complete than previous similar definitions._ This omits _purposes of_, which is redundant. It also omits _also_, which should **not** be omitted if it refers to some previous Definition you have already presented, but should be omitted if there is no other special referent outside your current presentation. Without context, it's impossible to tell which is the case here.

Comment: More complete almost always means more words, and more concise means shorter. I would choose the more accurate one. I would also drop *previous* as adding little.